# Unable to redirect mail from account to account with Postfix

Tags: postfix

I have read a lot of tutorials on how to do this but still nothing trying just to redirect from A to B.

Right now i am using at main.cf:

```
#virtual_alias_domains = $virtual_alias_maps
virtual_alias_domains = X.pt
#virtual_alias_maps = $virtual_maps
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/Library/Server/Mail/Config/postfix/virtual_maps/virtual
```

And in virtual i have:

```
teste@X.pt teste2@X.pt
```

After doing changes at this file i do,

```
postmap virtual
postfix reload
```

and nothing, all mails continues to go to A and not being forward to B.

I already was able to redirect one mail, but i just notice after changing both files several times.

Anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to know what was the problem that was causing this, and it was not easy because it was as i expected before a syntax error. So without a compiler this just turn a big nightmare .... and since i have not read this anywhere i will let here how i have managed that.

Till now i was using just spaces between input arguments in all files within postfix, and i discover in virtual_alias_maps file that i was using, that i should use TABs instead of spaces. And it was one day lost because of this ... i hope that my thread could help any one who may need.